# Return value for function within a slideUp() function

Tags: jquery

Basically I am trying to specify a return value for a function - but the return value is set in a slideUp() function that is within the main function:

```
function validateListing(form, hasError)
{
    var status;

    if (hasError)
    {
         scrollToTop();
    }
    else
    {
         $('.form').slideUp(function(){
             if ($('#user-form').hasClass('complete'))
             {
                 $('#confirm').show();

                 status = true;
             }
             else
             {
                 status = false;
             }
         });

         return status;
    }
}
```

The `return status` always seems to give 'undefined'. How can I fix this?

Comment: SlideUp is asych, you can instead invoke the method in the slideUpcallback with the status.

Answer (score 0):

The callback of the slide function is asynchronous, so it will be called after the value has been returned already.

Does the class of the element change while the form is sliding? Otherwise you can just check the class outside the callback of the slide:

```
function validateListing(form, hasError) {
  if (hasError) {
    scrollToTop();
  } else {
    $('.form').slideUp(function(){
      if ($('#user-form').hasClass('complete')) {
        $('#confirm').show();
      }
    });
    if ($('#user-form').hasClass('complete')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear enough that, how you are using your return value (`status`) but since this is an asynchronous function, you can't do it like this (traditional way of returning from function), instead, you can do something like this (maybe there are other ways)

```
function validateListing(form, hasError, func)
{
    var status = false;
    if (hasError) {
        scrollToTop();
    }
    else {
        $('.form').slideUp(function(){
            if ($('#user-form').hasClass('complete'))
            {
                $('#confirm').show();
                status = true;
            }
            else {
                status = false;
            }
            // call the callback function with status as argument
            func(status);
        });
    }
}
```

So, call the function with a callback function as it's third argument, like this

```
validateListing('.form', false, function(status){
    // write the code here that return value suppose to do
    alert(status);
});
```

So, the `callback` function will do the job for you that you are trying to do after function `returns` the status. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cuech/) (submit the form with a value in textbox), you'll get true instead of false and it'll be exposed via the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

To use in a async functions you could use deferred.promise()

```
function validateListing(form, hasError)
{
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();

    if (hasError)
    {
         scrollToTop();
    }
    else
    {
       var test = $('form').slideUp(function(){
             if ($('#user-form').hasClass('complete'))
             {
                 $('#confirm').show();

                 dfd.resolve( true );
             }
             else
             {
                 dfd.resolve( false );
             }
         });

        return dfd.promise();
    }
}

$.when( validateListing('testForm') ).then(
  function( data ) {
    status = data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

see the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lahmizzar/pq2hZ/) (Don't know your set of html code, so its a small test env)

The deferred.promise() method allows an asynchronous function to prevent other code from interfering with the progress or status of its internal request. The Promise exposes only the Deferred methods needed to attach additional handlers or determine the state (then, done, fail, always, pipe, progress, and state), but not ones that change the state (resolve, reject, notify, resolveWith, rejectWith, and notifyWith).

To learn more about Deferred's Promise objects please have a look at [here](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)